# Разбиение периода времени на подпериоды - PHP

Tags: php, дата, время, datetime

Есть период времени

```
$start = '10:00';
$end = '12:30';
```

Как можно разбить время на интервалы по 30 мин, чтоб выводилось:

```
10:00-10:30
10:30-11:00
11:00-11:30
11:30-12:00
12:00-12:30
```

Нужно чтоб период программно разбивался с заданным диапазоном (в примере 30 мин), так как `$start` и `$end` заранее не известные. В результате должен получиться массив с результатом разбивки как выше.
Спасибо за любые идеи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция sttrtotime понимает задание интервала, на который изменить время. Этим можно воспользоваться например, так

```
$start = '10:00';
$end = '12:30';

$st = strtotime($start);
$et = strtotime($end);

while($st < $et) {
  $t = strtotime("+30 minute", $st);
  echo date("H:i", $st)."-".date("H:i", $t)."\n";
  $st = $t;
  }
```

вот, что получается

```
10:00-10:30
10:30-11:00
11:00-11:30
11:30-12:00
12:00-12:30
```